# How to implement Russian bibliographic data?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, languages

```
@article{когбетлянц1915объ,
  title={Объ однократно-суммируемыхъ рядахъ Sturm-Liouville'я},
  author={Когбетлянц, Эрванд Геворгович},
  journal={Сообщенiя Харьковскаго математическаго общества},
  volume={14},
  number={6},
  pages={251--270},
  year={1915},
  publisher={Императорский Харьковский университет}
}
```

How to implement this Russian bibliographic data to BibTeX (`.bib`) file?

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to BibTeX? If not, with BibLaTeX it's pretty simple: You just put the article data inside your bib-file as is.

Unless you compile with xelatex or lualatex, you need to make sure to load `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}`. Just have a go at it:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{demo-russian.bib}
@article{когбетлянц1915объ,
  title={Объ однократно-суммируемыхъ рядахъ Sturm-Liouville'я},
  author={Когбетлянц, Эрванд Геворгович},
  journal={Сообщенiя Харьковскаго математическаго общества},
  volume={14},
  number={6},
  pages={251--270},
  year={1915},
  publisher={Императорский Харьковский университет}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{demo-russian.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

There is this great Russian article I'd really like to quote: \cite{когбетлянц1915объ}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

## Update

Thanks to UlrikeFischer's excellent comments, I have learned how to get rid of the `filecontents`-package. File should compile without the warning now.

Here's the output:

[image: Russian bibliographic data]

Comment: `bibencoding=utf8` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` aren't needed with a current tex system/latex/biblatex, both are set by default.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, great, thank you, will edit right away!

Comment: and regarding  filecontents: remove the package and use `\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{...}` if you want to overwrite an existing file. But I would use a bit more unique name, e.g. `demo-russian.bib`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, excellent! Edit has been made.